# App keeps crashing while checking for user sign in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

```
package com.example.demo.myblog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mReclBlogMainList; //The main recycler view for listing posts
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
//                    finish(); //can't go back to previous activity # MainActivity
                }
            }
        };

        //All our posts reside inside the Blog directory under the database root
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        //Initialize Recycler View
        mReclBlogMainList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reclBlogMainList);
        mReclBlogMainList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //setting a layout manager for recycler view -- vertical list
        mReclBlogMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //adding auth state listener
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        //Creating adapter after creating view holder class below
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
                //setting title, desc, image to view holder after fetch from database
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage()); //since View holder is static class
            }
        };
        //setting up recycler view with firebase adapter
        mReclBlogMainList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    //inflate the menu created in the main_menu file
    // onto the top menu bar of the app
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //called when user selects any icon on the inflated menu
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){
            // if the user has clicked on the '+' icon
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //For setting up a recycler view, we need a view holder
    //Creating view holder after setting up Blog class
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        //Set the title and desc for the recycler view posts
        public void setTitle(String title){
            TextView postTitle = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostTitle);
            postTitle.setText(title);
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc){
            TextView postDesc = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostDesc);
            postDesc.setText(desc);
        }
        //as it's inside a static class
        public void setImage(Context ctx, String imageUrl){
            ImageView postImage = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imgPostImage);

            //with the application context, load the image from
            //the file url into the image view
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageUrl).into(postImage);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main page of a simple blog app. I am trying to check for user sign in using the `AuthStateListener` in the `OnCreate` function. However, it never gets called when I launch the app.

Also, when I add the auth state listener to Firebase auth instance in the `OnStart` function, my app crashes on lauch.

What am I doing wrong? How do I check for user login?

I am using the Google sign in for Firebase.

I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo.myblog/com.example.demo.myblog.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: can you show you error

Comment: When I launch the app it just crashes. I gave a generic error like failed to load the app.

Comment: You need to check the logcat output for the logs, not just the popup window on the screen...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion csm_dev. I found the error. I was using the wrong theme for Login Activity. I changed it back and everything is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this error line:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo.myblog/com.example.demo.myblog.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

You need to use Theme.AppCompat for the `MainActivity` theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`

You need to use the theme from `res/style.xml` like this:

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please initialize an object of FirebaseUser inside onCreate method like below -

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

and in your Activity's onStart method just check

```
if (user != null) {
         // Your user is authenticated 
        // Do your tasks;
        }
```